# AFNetworking 2.0 custom header for POST

Tags: ios, post, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am trying to perform POST request with custom header but I keep getting this exception and app failure:

```
'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<AFHTTPRequestSerializer 0xa21af80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X-Auth-AID.'
```

I have followed instructions on forum of the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1572):

Both this

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
AFHTTPRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
[requestSerializer setValue:@"test" forKey:@"X-Auth-AID"];
manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;
```

and this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"test" forKey:@"X-Auth-AID"];
```

is throwing the exception...

Comment: Can you share  the exception.

Comment: It is already written there...NSUnknownKeyException.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method you want to use is [setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFHTTPRequestSerializer.html#//api/name/setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:), which is defined on `AFHTTPRequestSerializer`. The method you're currently calling is [setValue:forKey:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/setValue:forKey:), which is defined in the the `NSKeyValueCoding` protocol and not what you want.